# replace the filename of transferred file from gmail to gdrive with filenameDATE

Tags: date, google-apps-script, rename, gmail-api, gdrive

I have script that can transfer email from gmail to gdrive and my plan is replace the filename of the email attachment to assigned filename with current date ddmmyy (Ex. project012322.xlsx) or .csv when the file is transferred to gdrive.

May I know what I need to modify or add with my script?

```
  const searchItem = "in:inbox subject:(My Project) has:attachment";
  const threads = GmailApp.search(searchItem, 0, 100);
  const ids = threads.flatMap((thread) => {
    const messages = thread.getMessages();
    return messages.map((message) => {
      const id = message.getId();
      if (!values.includes(id)) {
        const attachments = message.getAttachments({ includeInlineImages: false, includeAttachments: true });
        attachments.forEach((attachment) => {
          Drive.Files.insert({ title: attachment.getName(), mimeType: attachment.getContentType(), parents: [{ id: folderId }] }, attachment.copyBlob());
        });
      }
      return [id];
    });
  });
```

Comment: What is `project` of `project012322.xlsx`?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, currently my script only using the email subject to filter and download the attachment, is it possible to change or assign a filename when the file is transferred to gdrive? like my example?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand `project` of `project012322.xlsx`? For example, when the filename of the attachment file is "sample", do you want to change the filename from `sample` to `project012322.xlsx`?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, No, currently my script cannot assign an specific filename for the uploaded file in gdrive it only transfer the email attachment to gdrive when the criteria of the assigned subject is found in the email inbox my plan is to have an assigned filename when the email attachment is uploaded to gdrive, is it possible to do it with my current script?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I added the search criteria on my script as you can see it only download the file using the subject assigned on the script this is for gmail, when the script found an attachment on that subject it will automatically download the file from it and save it to gdrive with original filename, my plan is when the file is transferred to google drive it will change the filename to (ex. My_project_012322.xlsx) like this with added date and some special character like underscore. is it possible to do it with my current script?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `(ex. My_project_012322.xlsx) like this with added date and some special character like underscore. is it possible to do it with my current script?`, what is `My_project` of `My_project_012322.xlsx`? You want to change the filename from the original filename to the text of the email title and the date. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: And, if there are multiple attachment files in an email, do you want to use the same filename for each file?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, Yes, but if possible to filter it and download only based on filename assigned on the script it would be great. like blob I think?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, my plan is to modify my script to have naming convention like when the file is transferred or downloaded to gdrive it will have specific filename with date and underscore, since the current script can only download the file with the original filename name what ever the filename of the attachment in gmail.

Answer (score 0):

- Your script contains the line
  `Drive.Files.insert({ title: attachment.getName(), mimeType: attachment.getContentType(), parents: [{ id: folderId }] }, attachment.copyBlob());`  with `title: attachment.getName()`
- This means that you are creating a file on your Drive with the title that is exactly the same like the original name of the attachment
- If instead you would like to give the file an assigned name plus the current date - you need to define the assigned name and get the current timestamp
  For this, you can replace the line above by the following three lines:

```js
var myName = "project";
var currentDate = new Date();
Drive.Files.insert({ title: myName + " " + currentDate, mimeType: attachment.getContentType(), parents: [{ id: folderId }] }, attachment.copyBlob()); ` with `title: attachment.getName()
```

- Use [new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to retrieve the current timestamp
- If you would like to fromat the timestamp retrieved by `new Date()` - use [Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)